# Fight differences between One Punch Man anime/manga/webcomic?

Tags: one-punch-man

I realize that all three are at different spots story arc-wise, but I was wondering if there were any other discrepancies in terms of fights between the three at the point where the anime is currently at? Ex. I thought I remember reading that the monster "Personification of a Light Cord" had its own little section where Saitama fights it in the manga, but in the anime it only appears briefly as Saitama recounts some of his past enemies in the pilot episode.

Note that this is specifically referring to the battles of the series (much less general given that unique fights are typically only 2-3 per episode, at maximum) that have been present in either the manga/webcomic form but not in the anime one at the point where the anime is currently at.

Comment: The Light Pull Cord guy appears in a bonus chapter of the manga and isn't really part of the main story line.  You'd probably only see the full story animated in a DVD extra, but I don't think it has so far, and indeed the DVD extras/ovas seem unique and not based on the manga extras.